# I want to query the highest discount level for each customer with using Northwind

Tags: sql-server

I want to query the highest discount level **for each customer**, using `Rank()`.
But some of data is missing and I don't know why..
(I used database **Northwind**)

this is script I have tried..

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT ProductID, CustomerID, Discount,    
       RANK() over (partition by CustomerID order by Discount desc) as rank
FROM Orders
    JOIN [Order Details] 
        ON Orders.OrderID= [Order Details].OrderID
)

SELECT Distinct ProductID, CustomerID, Discount   

FROM CTE
    WHERE 
            Discount>0.1 and
            ProductID between 60 and 65 and
            rank=1
    order by CustomerID
```

before this process,
I tried this script beforehand

```
    select ProductID, customerID, Discount
from Orders
    join [Order Details]
        on orders.OrderID = [Order details].OrderID
where 
    Discount>0.1 and
    ProductID between 60 and 65
 order by ProductID, CustomerID
go
```

And I edit manually to get highest discount level for each customer.
I should have about 32 rows (It depends on if I remove repeated data or not)
But when I run first script, I just get 15 rows..
How can I solve this problem? Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe remove productID between and discount > 0.1

Comment: Those constraints you've mentioned are adapted to both scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating `RANK()` before you apply your filters, which means that some rows that were `Rank() = 1` could be eliminated by the filters.   Try moving your filters up into the `CTE`.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT productid,
                customerid,
                discount,
                Rank()
                  OVER (
                    PARTITION BY customerid
                    ORDER BY discount DESC) AS [rank]
         FROM   orders
                JOIN [order details]
                  ON orders.orderid = [order details].orderid
         WHERE  discount > 0.1
                AND productid BETWEEN 60 AND 65)
SELECT DISTINCT productid,
                customerid,
                discount
FROM   cte
WHERE  [rank] = 1
ORDER  BY customerid
```